# Use a mysql command to Insert a row into a db table using Terraform

Tags: mysql, terraform

I am using terraform and want to insert a row into a db. I am using a null_resource  with a mysql command. I was trying to figure out what the command would look like using terraform

I think the issue is with mysql command
missing delimiter for 'u' glob qualifier?

```
variable "environment" {
  default = "prod"
}
```

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "-u${username} -p${password} --port port_number -h 00.0.0.0 INSERT into table (column1,column2) VALUES(${var.values},${var.values});"
    interpreter = ["mysql", "-Command"]
    environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're using a local-exec provisioner with a null resource why do you think it would it look any different than running locally on the command line?

Comment: you need to use `.... -e "INSERT into table (column1,column2) VALUES(${var.values},${var.values});"` you will need to escape the double quotes...